# Dynamically changing text box values ​related to the on change event of a Select does not work

Tags: javascript, html, view, filtering

I've always thought that people who have javascript in their head are real wizards haha, I'm very bad with this and I find myself automating some fields of a view at work and I don't know how to proceed, I have a recycled code of a method that executes changes in a Select from another select. I want to reuse it, but now I want it to agree to the value in my Select combo to be able to change the placeholder of a text field that I have next to it, and also change a label that indicates instructions for this select, my code is what I know It happened, if someone can help me make it work I would be very grateful! thank you!

My code is this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Input_cond2_operator").change(function() {
    $.get("GetOperatorObject", {
      ID: $("#Input_cond2_operator").val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#Input_cond2_operator").empty();
      $("#Input_cond2_operator").prop('disabled', false);
      console.log(data);
      if (data && data == "") {
        $("#Input_cond2_operator").append("<option value='ignore'>No information</option>")
        $("#Input_cond2_operator").prop('disabled', true);
      }
      $.each(data, function(index, row) {
        document.getElementById("Input_cond2_value").placeholder = row.subqry_suggested_value;
        document.getElementById("Input_cond2_description").value = row.subqry_supported_operator_description;
      });
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="ibox ">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Operator Condition 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select class="form-control" asp-for="Input_cond2_operator" id="Input_cond2_operator" asp-items="ViewBag.Condition2"></select>
          <label id="Input_cond2_description" class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="ibox ">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Values</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <input type="text" asp-for="Input_cond2_value" placeholder="" id="Input_cond2_value" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is that according to the value selected in: "Input_cond2_operator" to be able to bring its respective PlaceHolder ("Input_cond2_value") and value of its label ("Input_cond2_description")

I filter these two fields from the controller method called: GetOperatorObject, where I return a Json containing the values ​​for the place holder and the label.

My controller method in order to bring those two values that I need:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetOperatorObject(int ID)
    {
        var _brTypeMetadata = await _lkBusinessRulesTypeApplication.GetBusinessRulesTypeMetadataApplication();
        List<Lk_business_rules_type_metadata> _brTypeMetadataResult = new List<Lk_business_rules_type_metadata>();
        foreach (var item in _brTypeMetadata)
        {
            if (item.Rule_type_metadata_id == ID)
                _brTypeMetadataResult.Add(item);
        }
        return Json(_brTypeMetadata);
    }
```

Entity returned in Json:

```
    [Display(Name = "Supported operator")]
    public string Subqry_supported_operator { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supported operator description")]
    public string Subqry_supported_operator_description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value field - is active flag")]
    public bool? Is_subqry_value_active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Supported value type")]
    public string Subqry_supported_value { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public string Subqry_suggested_value { get; set; }
```

Comment: There are no options in your select, can you update the snippet?

Comment: The `$.each` loop updates the same elements each time through the loop. So at the end it will just contain the information from the last item in the array. What's the point of the loop?

Comment: `if (data && data == "")` will never succeed. An empty string is falsy.

Comment: Yes, the if and the .each was from the previous method, i thought that I could use in this... but refreshing ("Input_cond2_description") and ("Input_cond2_value")

Comment: can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't use AJAX here, so I've substituted a static array of objects.

Find the element of the data that corresponds with the selection value, and use that to update the properties of the input element.

```js
const data = {
  1: { value: "Value 1", placeholder: "Placeholder 1"},
  2: { value: "Value 2", placeholder: "Placeholder 2"}
};

$("#select").change(function() {
  let settings = data[$(this).val()];
  if (settings) {
    $("#input").val(settings.value).prop("placeholder", settings.placeholder);
  } else {
    $("#input").val("").placeholder("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: Hi! I love your answer and it clearly solves the problem, but I need to get both values from database because they are constantly changing...

row.subqry_supported_operator_description;
row.subqry_supported_operator_description; 

Are the two values that I am getting from the controller  with  $.get("GetOperatorObject", {
      ID: $("#Input_cond2_operator").val()

Comment: The principle is the same, you just do it in the AJAX callback function.

Comment: Hi again! I am very new into JS, what the use of let ? and val ? really I dont understand how to mix my previous code whit your answer... sorry :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to try to teach you JavaScript basics, there are many online tutorials. Those are how you declare local variables in a function.

Comment: OK no problem! just wondering why you bring a solution that has nothing to do with mi question, my question here is how to put 2 incoming values from the database into a change function... It is obvious that if I copy the entire database into a view I will be able to filter whatever I want, but it wouldn't cost to write 15000 records in a view, right? It seems that your answer totally ignores my code and how I am working. That is why I asked you to help me accommodate him, not to receive free lessons. Thank you the same for your comments and response

Comment: You didn't provide enough details to show the exact solution, so I showed the general principles of setting the attributes from an object. It doesn't matter where the object came from, it's the same when it comes from a controller or a hard-coded object.

Comment: Is the entity : Lk_business_rules_type_metadata  I will edit the post with this model get/sets

Comment: The Json is travelling trough the Setters of all the atributes of this entity.. so is getting the data I need, my problem is to capture this two fields in the JS method, while changing the selec

Comment: I don't know what that produces in JSON, can you show what `console.log(data)` looks like? And which fields you want to be used in the update.

Comment: I was able to solve it ! thanks to you for your patience...